# Trigger click on radio button as part of document ready

Tags: javascript, jquery, click

I have a dynamic radio button list as part of my application and, upon the user making a selection, I reveal additional content using a jQuery click function.  This all works fine unless the dynamic list of radio buttons only has one option.  With only one option, the radio button itself is selected by default, but the click event doesn't fire unless the user clicks the radio button.

Is there a way to trigger the click event at document ready so that, if there is only one option, the user doesn't have to make a redundant click?

This is the jQuery code I'm using which, again, works fine as long as the user makes a selection.

Thank you!

```
    jQuery('input[name="location"]').click(function(){
        var data = {location : jQuery(this).val()};
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: "/custom.php",
            type:'POST',
            data: data,
            dataType: 'html',
            success: function(result){
                jQuery('#div-custom').html(result).show();   
            }
        });
```

Comment: `jQuery('input[name="location"]').click(function(){
        var data = {location : jQuery(this).val()};
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: "/custom.php",
            type:'POST',
            data: data,
            dataType: 'html',
            success: function(result){
                jQuery('#div-custom').html(result).show();   
            }
        }).trigger('click'); `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check how many radio buttons your selector matched by checking the `length` property. If it's one you can then trigger the click on that button manually, like this:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    var $locations = $('input[name="location"]').click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            url: "/custom.php",
            type:'POST',
            data: { location : $(this).val() },
            dataType: 'html',
            success: function(result) {
                $('#div-custom').html(result).show();   
            }
        }); 
    });

    if ($locations.length == 1)
        $locations.click();
});
```

Note also that the first parameter of the document.ready handler is a reference to jQuery, so you can alias that variable as the normal `$` to avoid having to use the verbose `jQuery` everywhere.

Comment: Perfect - THANK YOU!

Comment: No problem, glad to help